# Why are "People" different between macOS and iOS Photos?

Tags: icloud, photos, macos, ios

I had assumed that macOS and iOS photos would be synchronized through iCloud (assuming all iCloud features are enabled) but the people I see in "People" on iOS are not the same as the ones I see on macOS.

As of today, iOS has spent days finding people and has nearly completed the process, but when I look in Photos on macOS, I see two contradictory things, neither of which is very comforting:

- Photos on macOS says it is just starting to scan for people, even though the process on iOS is nearly complete, and
- Photos on macOS shows a different but larger set of people (with different photos, completely different numbers, and names, connected to contacts, which iOS lacks).

This is unexpected, since Photos is synced through iCloud.

What's going on here:

- Why do Photos need to be scanned again for faces on macOS, even though they've already been scanned on iOS?
- Why are there already Faces in macOS; and why are they different?
- Why isn't iOS aware of the name sand contact entries associated with the people they do share (at least by actual person)?

Why are "People" different between macOS and iOS Photos (and [how does that make any sense](https://photos.google.com))?

Comment: I already had to redo these faces more than 5 times including after certain beta updates and after upgrading to the iPhone 7 and today it's again gone after resetting my iPhone 7 due to another issue and doing a full iCloud restore; so to get to the bottom of it for some reason Apple has decided to keep the faces database on the phone itself and not sync it with iCloud.

Comment: @PinchusG.: Are you saying that People on macOS and People on iOS are different things?!

Comment: unfortunately that's exactly what I've learned the past few weeks

Comment: @PinchusG.: That can't possibly be the intent, can it. No wonder Apple is dead last in cloud services!

Comment: @PinchusG.: This nonsensical non-feature has been repaired in 10.1.1.